# How can I view the full URL after using MultipartEntityBuilder?

Tags: java, php, android, http-post, multipartentity

I am fairly confident this code works (I used it in another part of my project for a different API) as far as posting but I do not think the URL is being formatted correctly. I want to know if there is anyway to view the full URL after building all of the entities so I can see if the final URL is formatted correctly. Code:

My URL = http://pillbox.nlm.nih.gov/PHP/pillboxAPIService.php
Method = POST

API key = not going to post (works though)

drugName = just a string that has the name of a drug

I have logs in the code to try and view the url but they aren't returning anything close and the debugger isn't either.

I am trying to build the URL to look like this: 
http://pillbox.nlm.nih.gov/PHP/pillboxAPIService.php?key=My_API_KEY&ingredient=diovan

```
public String makeServiceCallPillBox(String url, int method, 
        String api, String drugName) 
{
    String resultEnitity = null; 
    try {
        // http client
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        HttpEntity entityResult = null;



        // Checking http request method type
        if (method == POST) 
        {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            // Butild the parameters
            MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
            builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE); 
            builder.addTextBody("key", api);
            builder.addTextBody("ingredient", drugName);; 
            final HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
            httpPost.setEntity(entity);
            Log.d("url", httpPost.toString());
            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            Log.d("post", builder.toString());
            Log.d("post2", entity.toString()); 

            entityResult = httpResponse.getEntity();

            resultEnitity = EntityUtils.toString(entityResult);

            Log.d("result", resultEnitity);

        }   

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return resultEnitity;

}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `am trying to build the URL to look like this`. Well that is only possible with a GET command. A POST will not put the data in the url to begin with.

Comment: Okay, well do I need to use the MultipartEntityBuilder still?

Comment: No. You need nothing. As an url with some get parameters you can easily construct yourself.